# Automator AppleScript - trying to echo a string variable to Bash

Tags: applescript, automator

I am trying to create a service using Automator.

Inside a Run AppleScript action I have a variable that is a string in which each line is a word separated by linefeed. Like this:

```
à
às
a
ante
ao
aos
após
aquela
```

When I try to echo this to terminal by doing:

```
do shell script "echo " & (finalText as string)
```

I get this error:

```
The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “sh: line 1: a: command not found
sh: line 2: à: command not found
sh: line 3: ante: command not found
...
sh: -c: line 30: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
sh: -c: line 30: `do'”
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "trying to echo a string variable to Bash" what is it exactly your are trying to do? I ask because using a `do shell script` _command_ in a **Run AppleScript** _action_ isn't going to do much of anything if all you are doing is echoing some strings of text, however, from the errors you are obviously doing more than that! Anyway, to get rid of the _command not found_ type errors, use: `do shell script "echo " & finalText's quoted form` -- As to the _syntax error near unexpected token `do'_ error, without seeing all of the _code_, it's impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: BRILLIANT. `'s quoted form` did the trick. Please make this command an answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the *command not found* type errors in this case, and just about anytime when passing a *variable* to a `do shell script` *command*, use:

```
do shell script "echo " & finalText's quoted form
```

You can also use:

```
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of finalText
```

Whichever you prefer as appropriate.